# How to change the title of the page?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

Can anyone tell that how to change the title of the page? Is it possible in SharePoint Designer? The below image with  yellow marked.[image]

Comment: You can do that by going to "SitePages" library and editing the properties of this page. However please note that the url will also get updated when you change the title. The other solution would be to add the javascript mentioned in the answers below to the page using a content editor webpart (Chrome type none and visibility hidden),

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Please try below code :

```
document.title = "Your Title Goes Here";
```

Answer (score 3):

That is not the title of the site, but instead - it's a title of a page. Go to the library where your pages are stored (in your case "Site Pages"), edit properties of that page and change the title to whatever to like.

Answer (score 3):

You can do so by clicking on the Edit button on the ribbon under Page tab to enter the edit mode or by clicking the Edit Properties button.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Should note that the pictures here are using 2010, so it may look different for the OP.